# Block onClick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to block a particular onClick function on my site. I have written the following but it doesn't appear to block the function. Any ideas?

It works if I remove ('xx=d&') but I only want it to block the function when this is present.

JS

```
function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm('xx=d&') (event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You are probably getting a syntax error on your console. Check it out.

Comment: This part `function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm('xx=d&') (event)` does not make sense, is supposed to be just `function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm(event)` if you want to pass more than 1 argument `function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm(arg1, event)` etc... But the question is where does 'xx=d&' come from? is it an id? class? a specific property of the element?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your constructor..

`function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm('xx=d&') (event){`

You have a hard string in there, where you should be having your parameter name.. and you've got two.. brackets which in your case is invalid... unless the function returns a function declaration which I assume your example doesn't.

Your constructor should look like the below:

`function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm(event){`

If you open Developer Tools > Console, you'll start seeing your JavaScript errors as pointed out in the comments section.

---

As per your question in the comments; you would do a simple string comparison:

```
var block = 'xx=d&';

function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm(event){
    if(block == 'xx=d&'){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

if you want to pass the 'block' variable as part of the constructor you need to add another variable:

`function AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm(event, block){`

And if you're using inline handler to execute the function; you must update it rather than hard-coding the string:

`<a href="/Home" onclick="AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm(event, 'xx=d&')">Test the Method</a>`

---

Going back to the dual brackets, if you want to know.. is actually a valid syntax as I mentioned above if your function returns a function declaration.

In this example, it's perfectly valid to use the double brackets.

```
var f = function(){
  return function(){
     console.log("123");
  }
}

f()();
```

But that might be outside the scope of what you're trying to do, and it's just something to learn ;)

Comment: Hi Adrian

Thank you for your help. I can block AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm but I only to block it with the following parameters AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm('xx=d&') . Are you able to advise a way I can do this? E.G. Blocks AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm('xx=d&') but doesn't block AJFK_AjaxUpdateForm('1234'). is this possible?

Comment: Where are you getting 'xx=d&' from? You can't hardcode a string into a constructor, I have added an edit hopefully addressing your issue.